# nginx 1.8 is removing port number from original url

Tags: tomcat, nginx

I have a https://public_IP:port_number/admin/ url that Nginx 1.8 passes to a web-app deployed on Tomcat 8 instance in a private server.The web-app first serves a login jsp based on Tomcat 'j_security_check' form authentication.

Now, on 'login' submit, the authentication happens successfully in background.

Post-authentication, a index.jsp( web.xml defined 'welcome-file') should be returned. But instead url changes to https://public_IP/admin/ i.e.port number gets removed & the welcome page does not get served!!!

My nginx.conf contains

```
location /admin {
        add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=9,chrome=1";
        proxy_pass http://<private_ip>:<port_num>/admin;
        proxy_set_header remote-addr $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        # Clear Connection header to enable keep-alive
        proxy_set_header Connection "";

        proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

....
      proxy_redirect $scheme://$server_name/admin/ https://$host:$server_port/admin/;
      proxy_redirect http://$server_name:$server_port/admin/ https://$host:$server_port/admin/
}
```

I am really struggling as to why port number does not get resolved...

Comment: Because you're proxying it and the `proxy_pass` directive reads `proxy_pass http://<private_ip>/admin;`

Comment: my bad...that was a typo...it's http://<private_ip>:<port_num>/admin

Comment: The redirect comes from tomcat. You may need to `proxy_redirect` whatever is coming back from tomcat. Use `curl` or browser tools to inspect the `Location` header in the response. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) for more.

Comment: I added a couple of proxy_redirect but still the issue remains

Comment: I have fixed the issue by tweaking the 'proxy_redirect' values.thank you